# Perl one liner to extract and sum numbers from a file

Tags: perl

I have a file with data.

*File:*

```
Rows: 2
...
...
Rows: 3
```

The command to search for 'Rows'.

```
perl -ne 'while (/Rows\:/gi) { s/([.]*Rows :)([.]*)/$2/i, s/^ *//; print }'`
```

*Gives:*

```
2
3
```

I want to sum up the value and give a result as 5 (2+3).

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

The `-n` flag puts the while loop for you, so you don't need to loop:

```
perl -lne '$s += $1 if /^Rows:\s*(\d+)/; END{print $s}' input
```

Comment: No, the `-l` flag handles newlines (`chomp`s and sets `$\ `). The `-n` flag adds a while loop.

Comment: OP was looping over regex

Comment: @mpapec, hmm you are right, but the sample input does not necessitate it.

Comment: No need to quote the `$s` in the final `print` statement.

Comment: @TLP .. thanks for the reply . Your suggestion worked but with a minor issue..:( the output shold come as 5 , but its coming as 23 .. its just taking the value , and printing instead of adding and printing the total. Pls help .

Comment: Hi,

The actual file has data               
Rows Inserted: 2
sdf
sdfsf
Rows Inserted: 3


${logfile} | perl -ne '$s += $1 if /^Rows Inserted:\s*(\d+)/; END{print $s}'`

This code is returning blanks.
So we tried this ${logfile} | perl -ne 'while (/Rows Inserted\:/gi) { s/([.]*Rows Inserted:)([.]*)/$2/i, $sumins+=$2, s/^ *//; print "$sumins" }'`

This is returning 23

Comment: Hi, The actual file has data 

    Rows Inserted: 2 
    sdf 
    sdfsf 
    Rows Inserted: 3 




    ${logfile} | perl -ne '$s += $1 if /^Rows Inserted:\s*(\d+)/; END{print $s}'` 

This code is returning blanks. So we tried this 


    ${logfile} | perl -ne 'while (/Rows Inserted\:/gi) { s/([.]*Rows Inserted:)([.]*)/$2/i, $sumins+=$2, s/^ *//; print "$sumins" }'`

 This is returning 23

Comment: try this:  `perl -ne '$s += $1 while /Rows Inserted:\s*(\d+)/gi; END{print $s}'`